# Performance of deleting many rows from an autofilter in VBA

Tags: excel, performance, vba, filter

I would like to know if there is a faster way do this than the code I am using. I got the code using xlUp from the recorder.

```
 rCnt = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
 ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$J" & rCnt).AutoFilter Field:=5, _
      Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(arrCodes), Operator:=xlFilterValues
 Rows("2:" & rCnt).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

And actually, if there was some way to flip the filter, I wouldn't need to delete at all as this is a temporary table that I copy from. However, all my research has failed to find a way to do

```
Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(<>arrCodes)
```

and arrCodes has too many elements to list in the filter. And the stuff that is not in arrCodes is way too numerous to make an array from. Thanks.

Comment: I take "flip" to mean inverse/opposite as in `Not`.  With that, if I was doing this outside of VBA, I would do the "inverse" search by filtering, coloring visible cells, and then filtering on non-colored cells.  You can then copy your inverted filter to somewhere else.  You can also use the `Advanced Filter` to specifically search for a long list of `<>item` type criteria.

Comment: I might try your color idea. If I filter what I want deleted and then color it red, re-filter on non-red cells, I would have what I need without deleting. That is my assumption anyway.

Comment: That's how I normally do it.  Much easier to test with normal UI instead of VBA to see if it does what you want.

Comment: This worked great. It was almost instantaneous. It allows me to manipulate the table and get what I want visible so I just quickly copy it to the master table. Thanks. Am I able to mark a comment as an answer or do you need to submit this idea as an answer?

Comment: I added it as an answer so you can accept if it was what worked.  I'll delete the comments in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just use Excel UI and not formulas or VBA, you can do the following simple steps to get an "inverse" filter.  This could then be ported to VBA if needed:

- Apply the filter with the opposite conditions
- Color those cells in one column (either font or background)
- Clear the filter
- Filter again but this time by cells in that column without color
- Copy those results where you want them

This will not work well if the column already has some background colors.  If that is the case, you can add a new column and color it.  If this is in VBA, you could automate those steps.  There are limits, but this is quick and simple if it applies.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I did have to set all visible cells to NoFill as the report the spreadsheet was exported from colored them. I also performed this in VBA but I couldn't figure out how to put the code in the comments to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in the past with building then deleting a range. You can combine ranges with `Union()`. I've attached a bit of example code, it's not wonderful but it shows the basic concept. This example deletes rows with odd numbers in column A in rows 2 through 11.

```
Public Sub DeleteRows()
  Dim deleteThis As Range

  For i = 2 To 11
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value Mod 2 = 1 Then
      If deleteThis Is Nothing Then
        Set deleteThis = Sheet1.Rows(i)
      Else
        Set deleteThis = Union(deleteThis, Sheet1.Rows(i))
      End If
    End If
  Next i

  deleteThis.Delete xlShiftUp
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're unsure of how to test your arrCodes in this fashion just ask. I'm assuming it's a range your transposing.

Comment: arrCodes is an array that I read from a column (allowing items to be added in the future). It needs to be transposed to get the filter to work. Is looking at each row, building a range, and then deleting it quicker than just  deleting the results of a filter? I ask because the filter part is instantaneous and you then have everything to delete visible.

Comment: If you must use the AutoFilter object I'd suggest selecting the visible cells using `rangeObjectg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`, clearing the filter, then deleting them. If you're copying the cells, still select the visible cells before copying but you don't have to clear the filter. If written correctly doing the filtering in VBA and building the selection (range object) in VBA should be as fast or faster. You can also turn off screen updates and calculations when the VBA code is running.